# $R^n - \{0 \}$ simply-connected and curl?

Tags: general-topology

Every argument I've seen says $R^n - \{0 \} $ is simply connected because every Jordon curve (simply closed) can get "around" $0$.I don't understand what that means.

And if $F$ is a vector field on $R^n - \{ 0 \}$, how are we sure that it is not the curl of another vector?

I know that $div F = div cur l F  =0$ holds on simply-connected sets.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$ is simply connected only for $n>2$.

In $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ a closed Jordan curve that has the hole $\{0\}$ in this interior region cannot be continuously contracted to a point because, in such a process, we can only  contract the curve in the plane that contains the hole, so we cannot avoid it .

But if $n>2$ we can contract the curve moving  on  a surface that does not contain the hole (a.g., for $n=3$, a cap that has as border the given line), so we can avoid it.

So for $n>2$ we have that any close Jordan curve in $\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$ can be continuously contracted to a point and this means that this space is simply connected and any smooth closed $p-$form on it is an exact form, as say the [Poincaré lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar.C3.A9_lemma) (that is the general form of $div F=0 \Rightarrow F=rot H$ for $n-dimensional$ spaces).